# How to prove that $g(x)\equiv f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f,g$ are periodic functions, and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} [f(x)-g(x)]=0$, prove that  $f(x)\equiv g(x)$.

I've solved it if we add the condition that $f(x)$ is continuous.

But the continuity condition is un-needed.

==============
**additional remarks** =================

I know the fact that

$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} t(x)=0$ implies $\forall \{x_n\}\subset Dom(t)$, if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=+\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} t(x_n)=0$,

which is called **Heine Theorem** in my textbook.

But I don't think you can **put two different sequence** here even both of them turn to infinity.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is:

Let $p_1,p_2$ the periods of $f$ and $g$ respectively (suppose that are positive, in another case rewrite the proof). Now we have that $f(x + np_1) = f(x)$ and $g(x + np_2)= g(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. From hypothesis, for each fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\lim_{n \to +\infty} [f(y+ np_1) - g(y + np_2)] = 0$. By definition of limit in sequences, the last means that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a great $n$ such that
$$|f(y) - g(y)| = |f(y + np_1) - g(y + np_2)| < \epsilon$$
Then $|f(y) - g(y)|=0$, and this implies $f(y) = g(y)$.

Comment: The $<$ doesn't hold becase generally $y+np_1=y+np_2$. And if $\dfrac{p_1}{ p_2}$ is not rational, we cannot find any $m,n\in\mathbf{N}_{+}$ such that ￥、$y+mp_1=y+np_2$.

Comment: @闫嘉琦 The answer does not require $y+mp_1$ and $y+np_2$ are same. The answer just uses the definition of limit.

Comment: @HanulJeon Acutually I don't understand why $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} [f(y+np_1)-g(y+np_2)]=0$ holds

Comment: Inzit. Nice answer.

Comment: @闫嘉琦 Inzit use the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists **if and only if** every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ if for all $n$ we have $x_n\in\mbox{Dom}(f)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$, now define $h=f-g$ and use this fact to see how this limit holds

Comment: @Holo However, the question is: Here we only have: $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)-g(x)=0$, not $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} g(x)$. That is, you cannot just putting $x_n=y+np_1$, $y_n=y+np_2$ and induce $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)-g(y_n)=0$ from the fact you post. Or, you're not thinking this way, I don't know.

Comment: @PeterSzilas I still don't understand. I've re-editted what I learned from this answer, but I don't think this problem can use the **Heine Theorem** directly. Or you understand this answer in another way, then could you please tell me as more details as you can?

Comment: For fixed $y$ we have $$h(x)=f\left(y+\frac x{p_2}\right)-g\left(y+\frac x{p_1}\right),a_n=np_1p_2$$Now use Heine with a single sequence

Comment: @Holo Again, Why $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} h(x)=0$?

Comment: Oops, seems I missed something  reading the OP's answer.As you discussed already the OP is comparing 2 different points:$ y_1= y+np_1 \not  = y +np_2=y_2$.Taking limit as n goes to $\infty$ one cannot use  
limit $ |f(y)-g(y)| $ as y goes to $\infty$(same point y).If one has $n_1p_1=n_2p_2 =T$ as common period T, then comparing $|f(y+nT)-g(y+nT)| $as n goes to $\infty,$ for every y, seems fine.Otherwise I would not know.